# Can I share cookies to Android Browser from my App?

Tags: android, http, cookies

I want to inject cookies into Android Browser from My App's HttpClient's Cookie Store, is that possible, I do not mean WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Indirectly - your server can modify cookies that can be read by browser